# City's Satellite Images over Time?

Tags: geospatial, images

I'm interested in the landscape change (observed by satellites) for a certain city. I have found some videos where they show a city and how it evolved over the years.

My guess was that there are websites where they provide those images, I just couldn't find them. Do you know any databases/websites where I can find such historical satellite images?

Thanks

Comment: If they were using Landsat, it'd go back to the 1970s ... how far back are you trying to get?

Comment: @Joe minimum of 20 years back. Never heard of Landsat, any link for it?

Comment: @iturki [LandSat Look Viewer](http://landsatlook.usgs.gov/)